# clearinterval slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems to clearInterval on a slideshow of pictures. i've been reading a lot but i found nothing that could help me. Here is my code:

```
<script>  //under are my pictures sliding every 6 seconds (working well)
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var interval1= setInterval (function(){$('#imgvoy1').show(0).delay(36000);
  },0);
  var interval2 = setInterval (function(){
    $('#imgvoy2').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn(1000).show(0).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).hide(0).delay(24000)
  },0);
  var interval3 = setInterval (function(){
    $('#imgvoy3').hide(0).delay(11000).fadeIn(1000).show(0).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).hide(0).delay(18000)
  },10);
  var interval4 = setInterval (function(){
    $('#imgvoy4').hide(0).delay(17000).fadeIn(1000).show(0).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).hide(0).delay(12000)
  },0);
  var interval5 = setInterval (function(){
    $('#imgvoy5').hide(0).delay(23000).fadeIn(1000).show(0).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).hide(0).delay(6000)
  },0);
  var interval6 = setInterval (function(){
    $('#imgvoy6').hide(0).delay(29000).fadeIn(1000).show(0).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).hide(0).delay(0)
  },0);

  // and here is my code to make the slideshow stop when you click on #imagesprecsuiv element. Unfortunately, it does not work! 
  $('#imagesprecsuiv').click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval1);
    clearInterval(interval2);
    clearInterval(interval3)
    clearInterval(interval4);
    clearInterval(interval5);
    clearInterval(interval6)
  });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please format your code, and define "it does not work".

Comment: The code shown doesn't even balance parenthesis correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearInterval won't cancel any events that have been delayed using jQuery's .delay() function. These events can't be cancelled as you can read here ([.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)).

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Looking at your code the calls to setInterval aren't doing anything at all since you've given them a timeout of 0ms.

If you want each of these events to be cancellable then setTimeout and clearTimeout are probably your best bet (or setInterval but it's [moderately evil](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/setinterval-is-moderately-evil)), but you won't be able to chain all those things together which may also help make your code more legible.

Comment: Thank you i'll try with setTimeout then!